# [ABP Framework]Cannot start abp tiered authserver on linux as systemd service

Tags: linux, ubuntu, redis, abp

I have an abp tiered solution with redis enabled. I deployed the AuthServer project on an ubuntu server.When I use the dotnet command to run the program, it works fine. When I run it as a systemd service, it won't start.
I got the following journal log:

```
Oct 12 22:13:06 ubuntu auth.server[3398712]: [22:13:06 INF] Starting prime.business.AuthServer.
Oct 12 22:13:06 ubuntu auth.server[3398712]: [22:13:06 FTL] prime.business.AuthServer terminated unexpectedly!
Oct 12 22:13:06 ubuntu auth.server[3398712]: Volo.Abp.AbpInitializationException: An error occurred during ConfigureServicesAsync phase of the module prime.business.businessAuthServerModule, prime.business.AuthServer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. See the inner exception for details.
Oct 12 22:13:06 ubuntu auth.server[3398712]:  ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'configuration')
Oct 12 22:13:06 ubuntu auth.server[3398712]:    at StackExchange.Redis.ConfigurationOptions.DoParse(String configuration, Boolean ignoreUnknown) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConfigurationOptions.cs:line 646
Oct 12 22:13:06 ubuntu auth.server[3398712]:    at StackExchange.Redis.ConfigurationOptions.Parse(String configuration) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConfigurationOptions.cs:line 421
Oct 12 22:13:06 ubuntu auth.server[3398712]:    at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(String configuration, TextWriter log) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 1015
Oct 12 22:13:06 ubuntu auth.server[3398712]:    at prime.business.businessAuthServerModule.ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context) in D:\VSProjects\LTS\prime-business\src\prime.business.AuthServer\businessAuthServerModule.cs:line 150
Oct 12 22:13:06 ubuntu auth.server[3398712]:    at Volo.Abp.Modularity.AbpModule.ConfigureServicesAsync(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
Oct 12 22:13:06 ubuntu auth.server[3398712]:    at Volo.Abp.AbpApplicationBase.ConfigureServicesAsync()
Oct 12 22:13:06 ubuntu auth.server[3398712]:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Oct 12 22:13:06 ubuntu auth.server[3398712]:    at Volo.Abp.AbpApplicationBase.ConfigureServicesAsync()
Oct 12 22:13:06 ubuntu auth.server[3398712]:    at Volo.Abp.AbpApplicationFactory.CreateAsync[TStartupModule](IServiceCollection services, Action`1 optionsAction)
Oct 12 22:13:06 ubuntu auth.server[3398712]:    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionApplicationExtensions.AddApplicationAsync[TStartupModule](IServiceCollection services, Action`1 optionsAction)
Oct 12 22:13:06 ubuntu auth.server[3398712]:    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.WebApplicationBuilderExtensions.AddApplicationAsync[TStartupModule](WebApplicationBuilder builder, Action`1 optionsAction)
Oct 12 22:13:06 ubuntu auth.server[3398712]:    at prime.business.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\VSProjects\LTS\prime-business\src\prime.business.AuthServer\Program.cs:line 37
Oct 12 22:13:06 ubuntu systemd[1]: auth.server-gmbh-de-kestrel.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 12 22:13:06 ubuntu systemd[1]: auth.server-gmbh-de-kestrel.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.´
´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem now.
The cause is the wrong setting in the systemd service unit file. The WorkingDirectory was not set to the correct value. It should be the directory where the dll file is located, but I have set it to the parent directory, the application cannot then find the appsettings.json file to read the configuration.